# laptop making popping noise

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have ubuntu installed on my laptop, but the speaker makes a popping noise  (Capacitor discharge) every 10-30 second.. Im close to de soldering the  speaker by now!
I have tried:
edit intel-power-safe to
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false

arecord -l output:
**** Liste over CAPTURE-hardwareenheder ****
lydkort 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], enhed 0: ALC282 Analog [ALC282 Analog]
  Underenheder: 1/1
  Underenhed #0: subdevice #0

More detail on my problem is found here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/268181

Edit:
While earplugs are connected, the speaker still make a poping sound. The sound icon in the status bar changes from grey to red, or red to grey whenever the pop occours.(I have the system set on mute).

While unmuted, i get a system sound in the headset, and the onboard speaker pops.

Edit2:
I found the reason for the frequent system sounds! I have pidgin setup for facebook chat, and it was giving me a message everytime somebody logs on/off facebook.
I also discovered the popping noise doesn’t occur if i have the sound settings tab open (seems really wierd?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

I found a setting in the alsamixer called auto mute, disabling this did the trick!
exact steps:
open terminal and type "alsamixer"
Press f6 and choose the soundcard making the popping noise.
Navigate to automute and press down.

Hopefully, this can save other the trouble I been through